# Using AWS WAF to only allow specific file extensions for upload via forms

Tags: amazon-web-services, file-upload, amazon-waf, aws-waf-web-acl

We have a legacy web application which runs on Perl and Angular 1.8 and we have several forms from where files can be uploaded.
We have validations in place at the form submit level, but also want to introduce a check using WAF (AWS) to allow only a few file extensions that are uploaded as an additional security precaution.

We tried following the documentation from [here](https://repost.aws/knowledge-center/waf-block-file-extension-uploads), but it still allows all files for upload.

We tried changing the inspect type to the other possible options and also to match for file extensions, but this blocks even webpages from loading instead of just the uploaded files. Trying to match by content-type to multipart/formdata did not made a difference either.

Comment: What is the type of file that is getting uploaded in your web application that you want to control?

Comment: We want to allow xls, xlsx, csv and tsv. Rest of the extensions should be blocked. Our code does it, but want to add an additional security layer via WAF.

Comment: Tested to see that the detection is not fool proof. It does block some but let other slip through. So relying on WAF to decide based on the extension is not effective. I would recommend to do a validation of extension at upload page itself (if not doing that already)